# C OpenMP code acts unexpectedly on cygwin but just as expected on Linux

Tags: c, cygwin, openmp

```
int a = 0;
#pragma omp parallel private(a)
{
    a++;
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

With 4 cores one would expect this piece of code to print 1111, which it does on my Linux machine.

However, running the same piece of code (same flags etc) in cygwin on my Windows machine results in 11117 (not sure about the number of 1s).

The 7 is always there and a friend who tried the same also had the 7,
Any ideas how this happens?

I compiled the code with "gcc source.c -fopenmp -O2" on both machines.

Comment: This code has undefined behaviour as `a` has no defined value upon entrance to the `private` region. You probably want to declare `firstprivate(a)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did have difficulties to reproduce your error, since as I mentioned in my comment, your code has undefined behavior from an OpenMP standard point of view. Indeed, variables that are declared `private` upon entry of a `parallel` region do not get any initialization, unless they are declared `firstprivate`.

In your case, you increment a variable which value can be whatever, and print it. So the printed value can be whatever as well, included the one you expected to see.

I turns out that for me, in order to reproduce the series of 1s and a 7, I had to compile the code disabling any optimization from the compiler.
And once the code was fixed with `firstprivate`, all results were 1s.

Before fixing:

```
$ gcc -O0 -fopenmp foo.c
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=5 ./a.exe
71111
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=5 ./a.exe
17111
```

Code fixed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int a = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(a)
    {
        a++;
        printf("%d", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then

```
$ gcc -O0 -fopenmp foo.c
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=5 ./a.exe
11111
```